# [PFUserAuthenticationController registerAuthenticationProvider:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f96c1fa6090

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7

Getting this error in the logs:

```
2016-03-18 18:53:54.915 Tinder[715:229250] -[PFUserAuthenticationController registerAuthenticationProvider:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f96c1fa6090
2016-03-18 18:53:54.919 Tinder[715:229250] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFUserAuthenticationController registerAuthenticationProvider:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f96c1fa6090'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102e2ae65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104f0fdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102e3348d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d8090a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d804b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Tinder                              0x000000010249506a +[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:] + 225
    6   Tinder                              0x00000001023b3ccd _TFC6Tinder11AppDelegate11applicationfS0_FTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVSs10DictionaryCSo8NSObjectPSs9AnyObject____Sb + 541
    7   Tinder                              0x00000001023b4a53 _TToFC6Tinder11AppDelegate11applicationfS0_FTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVSs10DictionaryCSo8NSObjectPSs9AnyObject____Sb + 179
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001039e31f1 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 272
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001039e4397 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3415
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001039eacc6 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1760
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001039e7e7b -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    12  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010657e754 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
    13  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010657eac2 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d56a31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d4c95c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d4be13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d4b828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    18  UIKit                               0x00000001039e77cd -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    19  UIKit                               0x00000001039ec610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    20  Tinder                              0x00000001023b57ad main + 109
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000105a5a92d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

---

Also getting an error in my code:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

but I don't yet have any outlets in my code.

My code in AppDelegate.swift (personal info replaced by "xxx"):

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts

// If you want to use any of the UI components, uncomment this line
// import ParseUI

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    //--------------------------------------
    // MARK: - UIApplicationDelegate
    //--------------------------------------

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Enable storing and querying data from Local Datastore.
        // Remove this line if you don't want to use Local Datastore features or want to use cachePolicy.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

        let parseConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration(block: { (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "xxx"
            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "xxx"
            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "https://yourapp.herokuapp.com/parse"
        })

        Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(parseConfiguration)


        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

        PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()

        let defaultACL = PFACL();

        // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
        defaultACL.publicReadAccess = true

        PFACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser:true)

        if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
            // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
            // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
            // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

            let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
            let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
            var noPushPayload = false;
            if let options = launchOptions {
                noPushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil;
            }
        if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload) {
                PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
            }
    }
    if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
            let userNotificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
            let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge, UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert, UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound]
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
        }

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    //--------------------------------------
    // MARK: Push Notifications
    //--------------------------------------

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
        installation.saveInBackground()

        //        PFPush.subscribeToChannelInBackground("") { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) in
        //            if succeeded {
        //                print("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.");
        //            } else {
        //                print("ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel with error = %@.", error)
        //            }
        //        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        if error.code == 3010 {
            print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
        } else {
            print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication,
        openURL url: NSURL,
        sourceApplication: String?,
        annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
            return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }


}
```

Comment: Making a Tinder app?

Comment: Yes a tinder clone through a course

Comment: First, make sure you are using the latest libraries from Parse and Facebook. If you copied the dependencies from old instructions, they could be old versions. Secondly, look around the net to see if there is support with those libraries, as there may be other version combinations to make them work better. `Unrecognized Selected` typically means that a class that needs to be in your viewcontroller was not added

Comment: Yes, i am using all the latest libraries from Parse and Facebook.  I downloaded the latest SDKs

Comment: Your code does not contains call to registerAuthenticationProvider. Could you do a global search see where it is called?

Comment: I did a global search @YuchenZhong and i did not find it either.  I am new to IOS programming and i enrolled in an online course where this was the code given to us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this error doing the following:

First I deployed the official version of Parse Server (instead of Rob's version). Open this link and click 'Deploy to Heroku', follow the steps.
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example

After that I downloaded the Parse Frameworks (including Facebook framework) from the link below and replaced all current frameworks in my project with these frameworks downloaded.
https://parse.com/downloads/ios/parse-library/latest

Other than that just follow the class steps (adding code to AppDelegate, Info.pslist e etc.

Any problems, let me know.

Comment: Thanks @Rafael Did you use the Parse-Starter-Project located at http://www.robpercival.co.uk/parse-working-on-xcode-7swift-2/ ?

Comment: I did as you suggested and now stuck with the following error: -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)" in my logs.
I recreated app in developers.facebook.com and copied and pasted plist info into my plist and still stuck with this error

Comment: I fixed that error by adding <string>fbauth2</string> after CFBundleURLSchemes.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Check this link : [Parse - Facebook SDK Exception](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/550)

I think the problem is in this line of code:

```
PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
```

I see that you are using latest Facebook and Parse version. But are you sure the latest versions are referenced? (maybe in podspecs, or podfile). Try the old good command to delete Derived Data (cmd + shift + k and cmd + shift + alt + k)

This kind of error are due to a nil object referencing a method class. Check if this is happening also.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Sophy - I am referencing V4 for PFFacebookUtils.h but no luck

Comment: Fixed this error by going in and deleting all fb and parse sdks but getting a new error : FBSDKLoginManager logInWithReadPermissions:fromViewController:handler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fed38d61290